# A non-local corner ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, idempotents, local-rings

I am searching for a ring $R$ (preferably semisimple) and a nonzero primitive idempotent $e\in R$ such that the corner ring $eRe$ is not local. I am inspired by the theorems on semiperfect rings in which there are idempotents $e_i$ with each corner ring $e_iRe_i$ a local ring. I have also scanned the ERT site (the encyclopedia of ring theory), but to no avail. Thanks for any cooperation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seek a primitive idempotent which is not a local idempotent.

This is not possible in a semisimple ring, since these two notions coincide for semiperfect rings (Proposition 23.5 in Lam's *First course in noncommutative rings*)

Without additional conditions, it is fairly easy to find such idempotents: for example, $1\in \mathbb Z$ is primitive but not local.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would you please give me a "nontrivial" non-local idempotent which is primitive? Could the ring $R$ be Boolean in this regard?

Comment: Sorry! I meant by ERT the database of Ring Theory!

Comment: $(0,1)\in\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ is a "nontrivial" example. For boolean rings: obviously $eRe$ being an indecomposable Boolean ring implies $eRe=F_2$. So it is not possible in Boolean rings.

Comment: Why $eRe$ is boolean when $R$ is so?

Comment: @karparvar Because a subset of a boolean ring will satisfy the same identity?